# Passing URL parameters from php script to bash

Tags: php, bash

I'm trying to pass parameters from an URL (*PHP* script) to a *Bash* using a case control statement. The Bash script itself is working correctly, if run from the *Linux* machine, but calling via the URL returns and empty white page.

**The bash script**

```sh
case $1 in
allBG)
    echo "Prilagane na status 1 - All BG";
    cp /root/copyjob/status/xml/status1_allBG/tvip_provision.xml >/var/www/html/prov.mac/$2/tvip_provision.xml;
;;
allEU)
    echo "Prilagane na status 2 - All EU za"
    cp /root/copyjob/status/xml/status2_allEU/tvip_provision.xml >/var/www/html/prov.mac/$2/tvip_provision.xml
;;
eurotv)
    echo "Prilagane na status 3 - eurotv";
    cp /root/copyjob/status/xml/status3_eurotv/tvip_provison.xml >/var/www/html/prov.mac/$2/tvip_provision.xml;
;;
gotv)
    echo "Prilagane na status 4 - gotv";
    cp /root/copyjob/status/xml/status4_gotv/tvip_provision.xml >/var/www/html/prov.mac/$2/tvip_provision.xml;
;;
bixi)
    echo "Prilagane na status 5 - bixi";
    cp /root/copyjob/status/xml/status5_allbg/tvip_provision.xml >/var/www/html/prov.mac/$2/tvip_provision.xml;
esac
```

**The php script**

```php
$status = $_GET['status'];
$mac = $_GET['mac']; 

echo exec('/root/copyjob/status/status.sh $status $mac');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use double quotes, if you want the PHP to be interpreted or end your string and concat the variables to your string.

So its either:

```
echo exec("/root/copyjob/status/status.sh $status $mac");
```

or:

```
echo exec('/root/copyjob/status/status.sh ' . $status . ' ' . $mac);
```

**Edit:** Sorry, missed the echo. If you wanna output something from it you got to use the 2nd and 3rd parameter of exec:

```
<?php
$status = $_GET['status'];
$mac = $_GET['mac']; 
$output = array();
$return_var = null;
exec("/root/copyjob/status/status.sh $status $mac", $output, $return_var);

var_dump($output);
var_dump($return_var);
```

Comment: tried both these, still not working. I'm also checking if the script ran without an output , but it didn't.

Comment: The output now is  array(0) { } int(126) and unfortunately still not copying :(

Comment: Maybe worths mentioning that: 
1. this is nginx running php-fpm
2. exec and shell_exec commands are enabled
3. all the rights and permissions are there (for the purpose of the test i am running nginx as root)

Comment: int(126) means permission denied. The code seems to be correct. Working for me on my windows machine (without the cp part), even within the ubuntu subsystem as shell script. Try to remove the cp part and check if you get the output.

Comment: still getting the int(126). It's an ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS with all the latest updates. removed the cp command and i don't get the echo. I also tried putting /bin/cp and /bin/echo instead of the plain shell commands within the script/. chmoded the .sh script to 777 and checked all the permission - nginx still running as root. I also tried running the script from the console with php -v and the output is still the same

Comment: php itself should also have some configuration (user, group and listen.owner, listen.group, listen.mode). I would check those too.

Comment: I slighthly changed the setup. I moved everything within 1 directory and chowned it with www-data. You're right - php-fpm also runs with a different user, which is again www-data. I returned the nginx configuration to run as www-data, chowned everything and we have a small progress. The result now is array(0) { } int(0), but i still don't have the file copied. I also have fixed the paths in status.sh script which should be enough, but no.

Comment: In the end this worked... after your edit i stupidly copied everything without setting $status and $mac variable. now I accepted your answer - THANK YOU!